# Adding another author to a given title page

Tags: titles, templates

I have found a title page template which i have to edit a bit in, and that is causing me some problems. The template is intended to only contain one author name. However I have to have three names there. When i type the names after each other, the first two names goes on the first line, and then the last name on a second line. My question is then, is there any way to edit this template so that there are three author name boxes on top of each other?

```
%------------------------------------------------------------

 \newcommand*{\Forside}
 {\begingroup % Create the command for including the title page in the document

 \newpage
 \thispagestyle{empty}

\hbox{ % Horizontal box
\hspace*{0.2\textwidth} % Whitespace to the left of the title page
\rule{1pt}{\textheight} % Vertical line
\hspace*{0.05\textwidth} % Whitespace between the vertical line and title page text
\parbox[b]{0.75\textwidth}{ % Paragraph box which restricts text to less than the width of the page

{\noindent\Huge\bfseries Future Power Systems}\\[2\baselineskip] % Title
{\large \textit{How large a wind farm can be installed onto an existing grid, and which regulations are to be taken into account}}\\[4\baselineskip] % Tagline or further description

{\Large \textsc{NAME 1, NAME 2, NAME 3}} % Author name

\vspace{0.5\textheight} % Whitespace between the title block and the publisher
{\noindent \includegraphics[scale=0.3]{figures/logo.pdf}}\\[\baselineskip] % Publisher and logo
}}
\endgroup}

%\includegraphics[scale=0.4,clip=true,trim=0cm 9.5cm 15cm 9cm]{figures/ASE_logo.pdf}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: the three names can be put on separate lines by following each name by `\\ ` and adding `\par` before the end of the group that begins with `\Large`.

Comment: Thanks a lot - the \\ did the trick! What does the \par do? I have not included it, and the names are on three seperate lines now.


    {\Large \textsc{NAME1 \\ NAME2 \\ NAME2}} % Author name

Comment: `\par` ends the paragraph; since you used a font switch (`\Large`), using `\par` before closing the group makes sure that the right baselineskip is applied for the last line; perhaps you don't notice the effect in your specific case, but it's always required to use `\par` in a situation like yours to get the proper spacing between lines.

Answer (score 3):

the three names can be put on separate lines by following each name by `\\` and adding
`\par` before the end of the group that begins with `\Large`.

the shape of a paragraph isn't frozen until a paragraph ends.
since you've used a font switch (`\Large`), you need to end the paragraph to get
the baselineskip set properly for the last line, and `\par` does that.